# Does this site meet the Stack terms of service?

Tags: discussion

See
"qandasys dot info"

Which say
Question and Answer is proudly powered by WordPress.
Theme "The Fundamentals of Graphic Design" by Arjuna
Icons by FamFamFam

And I don't see any Creative Commons acknowledgement.